# How to sum over a big vector in Julia

Tags: sum, julia, biginteger

I am trying to take the sum of a very "big" vector, I know the `big()` function can be used for calculating large number, 
which I even used down below (and it works).
However, if I try to use it in a sum it doesn't work. 
I tried both `big(sum(test, dims=1))`  and `sum(big(test), dims=1))`  but I recieve following error:
`InexactError: Int64(-3331427209747016990720)`

```
test   = Tuple{Int, Int}[]
N = 80
Iterations = 60

for i in 1:10000
       push!(test, (big(largeNumber1(N, Iterations)) * big(largeNumber2(N, Iterations)), 0))        
end 

# this just transforms test into a vector
test = hcat(first.(test), last.(test)) * [1, 0]

sum(test, dims=1) # here is where the code "breaks"


<output> 1-element Vector{Int64}:
         -5233167026984513820
```

Most likely I am using `big()`  wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not show the code for largeNumber1(), but it seems that you are putting the big integer numbers into an Int64-tuple vector before you sum it.  Try

```
test  = Tuple{BigInt, BigInt}[]
```